# Azure Logic App FTP Get File Content fails

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have set up a logic app with the ftp trigger [When a file is added or modified (properties only)].  This works just fine when I upload a 50+MB file to that ftp server.  I have a [Get File Content] action set up right after the trigger. For the File input of the [Get File Content] action, I used the [List of Files Name] dynamic content from the trigger AND I have just filled in the path by using the available 'File Picker' (which connects to the FTP just fine).  When I test this out, it fails on the [Get File Content] action stating BadRequest and this Body.

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "An invalid request was made. Inspect the passed parameters and actions.\r\nclientRequestId: 7d9f2ff3-62d0-4f69-8cc5-f41c35297882",
  "source": "ftp-eus.azconn-eus.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

The inputs that come into the action show the correct file name and path. So I am confused on what it means by "Inspect the passed parameters and actions".  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

EDIT
Here are some screenshots to show. I don't get [File Name] as a dynamic option from my trigger. It doesn't even matter though, I can pick the exact file I want downloaded from the FTP Picker and it still fails. See screenshots:

Dynamically select file:
[image]

Statically select file:
[image]

Same result from both of them:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Get file content` to pick file, you could find the input of File is the Path of the file you want, so you could not get the file content just with the File content. You could use File path or File name, if you want to use the File name you should also know the path.

If you want to use File name, the input would be like this, this is a little inconvenient.

[image]

Or just with the File path. Actually the inputs in these two ways are same, so they all could get the file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I updated my question showing screenshots. It doesn't matter what I put into the Get File Content input, it fails with a 400 BadRequest error.

Comment: @Aarron H, please post your output , is there any message there?

Comment: I posted the JSON output originally, it has a message in there stating that "An invalid request was made. Inspect passed parameters"

Comment: @AarronH did you ever fix this?

Comment: @JBoothUA No, I couldn't get it to work. Had to go with another solution, where we setup a middle man service worker to get the FTP files and send them into our network from trusted location.

Comment: thank you.  i think we're looking into some sort of special integration also.  drats!